# repeat control from categorized view

Tags: xpages

I have tried to get the column values in repeat control from Categorized view in xPages,that time i got the column values are coming with single row,and the same row repeated

How to get the column values in "**repeat control from categorized view**"?

Thanks

Comment: How are you retrieving the data from the categorized column? And how are you presenting this data to the Repeat? The Repeat will iterate though an array of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a situation where I had to drill down from a much larger view and repeated the info back out with the following.

View is categorized in first column by what I'm drilling down by. I achieve this in the XPage/Custom Control by defining the view as a source in the data tab, then select "filter by category name", bind my repeater to that view data source, and compute the value I'm drilling down.

Then in my repeated table, each of my computed fields for each of the column entries read like:

```
rowData.getColumnValues()[1]
```

Adjust for your other columns by position with the array modifier after your getColumnValues method. This is not an elegant solution, but worked for my needs. Hope this helps if it's what you're looking for.

[Update]

It's worth noting that doing this can potentially create a memory handle for any *DateTime* objects which may be returned in the entirety of the `getColumnValues` method. If you're going to use this approach, I strongly recommend getting a handle on the column values separately, so you can perform a `session.recycle(colVals);` on them to prevent any memory creep.

[/Update]